# How to avoid no-wrapper tags on regions?

Tags: theming

**How do I make sure ALL regions are wrapped according region.tpl.php?**

In a subtheme of Zen I have created my own regions and modified the page.tpl.php file to something like the following:

```
<div #page>
    <?php print render($page['header']); ?>
    <?php print render($page['content']); ?>
    <?php print render($page['footer']); ?>
</div>
```

Some of the regions get a region wrapper from region.tpl.php, others get the code from no-wrapper.tpl.php (no wrapper). How can have all regions receive a wrapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid region-content blocks from receiving the block--no-wrapper.tpl.php template, go to template.php in your sub-theme and unquote or add the final function:

```
function zen_expeditiedokter_preprocess_block(&$variables, $hook) {
    if ($variables['block_html_id'] == 'block-system-main') {
        $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'] = array_diff($variables['theme_hook_suggestions'], array('block__no_wrapper'));
    }
}
```

This will give the block.tpl.php template to the content region (without editing the Zen main theme) and thus avoiding the no-wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

From the code it looks like Zen adds that template suggestion in `zen_preprocess_region()`, but only to the content region:

```
elseif ($variables['region'] == 'content') {
  // Allow a region-specific template to override Zen's region--no-wrapper.
  array_unshift($variables['theme_hook_suggestions'], 'region__no_wrapper');
}
```

If you're editing the Zen theme directly (which you shouldn't be :P) just remove those 4 lines; if you're creating a sub-theme, implement your own region preprocess function, copy the code from Zen's, and leave those lines out:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_region(&$variables, $hook) {
  // Sidebar regions get some extra classes and a common template suggestion.
  if (strpos($variables['region'], 'sidebar_') === 0) {
    $variables['classes_array'][] = 'column';
    $variables['classes_array'][] = 'sidebar';
    // Allow a region-specific template to override Zen's region--sidebar.
    array_unshift($variables['theme_hook_suggestions'], 'region__sidebar');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Clive, but the content region is still receiving the wrapper code from no-wrapper.tpl.php.

Comment: Did you clear Drupal's caches since making the change?